# React firebase htmltopdf ошибка с картинками

Tags: reactjs, firebase

При формировании pdf файла.
Firebase не отдавал картинку из storage для файла, жаловался на права доступа.

Решение.
создаем файл cors.json в проекте, рядом с папкой src.
В файле

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

устанавливаем gsutil

в командной строке

gsutil cors set ./cors.json gs://stafftogo-8721b.appspot.com

./cors.json --- путь к файлу
stafftogo-8721b.appspot.com --- REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET='stafftogo-8721b.appspot.com'

Comment: Так в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: Хотите такое сделать красиво, измените текст вопроса на вопрос с ошибкой, затем сами ниже добавьте ответ-решение.